# Activate SharePoint Central Admin from console

Tags: administration, central-administration

I've accidentally disable the Central Admin service on my sharepoint server and now I can't find a way to re-activate it.  Is there any way to do this using one of the SP command line utilities?

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to reactivate it through Services under Administrative Tools in the start menu?

Answer (score 1):

James, it's not a Windows service. You have to start it with Powershell:

http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/howto-start-the-sharepoint-2010-central-administration-service-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You should check-out the following:

- SharePoint 2010 Administration (**Run** > **Services.msc**)
- SharePoint Central Administration v4 application pool (**IIS Manager** > **Application Pool**).
- Check status of **SharePoint_AdminContent_** database (if default).

You can describe clearly your error message.